# Is it possible to query which LineStrings are near another LineString in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

If I have a MongoDB collection C with LineStrings {L1,L2,...,LN} composed of several points each **and** an extra LineString L0 not present in C, is it possible to query C for the nearest ones to L0?

I was trying without success something in line with the following:

A) Create geo index:

```
MongoConnection.getInstance().createIndex(DB, collection, new BasicDBObject("coordinates", "2d"), "geospacialIdx");
```

B) Add each LineString as:

```
double [][] points = new double[N][2];
points= <- add coordinates
MongoConnection.getInstance().getCollection(DB,COLLECTION).insert(
new BasicDBObject("coordinates",points));
```

C) Query:

```
double [][] points = new double[N][2];
points= <- coordinates of L0 
MongoConnection.getInstance().getCollection(DB, COLLECTION).find(new BasicDBObject("$near",new BasicDBObject("coordinates",points)))
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: No. The `$near` and variants all require a `Point` type ( or legacy pair ) and don't accept other objects. `$geoWithin` accepts "shapes", but a `LineString` is never "iwthin" a `LineString`. IMHO I have actually found it more useful to always store `Point` types, and instead of using things like `LineString`, I just put other things in the document that says *"These things are part of a group of things!"*. If I need `LineString` as external data, then read the "group" and write the `LineString`. This seems to work best with the database logic implemented.

Comment: Forgot to mention `$geoIntersects`, but of course the reliance there is on the supplied shape actually intersecting with another. So that's not really "near" either.

Comment: @NeilLunn, thanks for the response. Don't you want to post it as an answer instead?